# Drag and drop images uploading supported by IE

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I found several libraries and questions about that topic, but till now I couldn't find a library that allows drag and drop images and is supported by IE, could you please help me 
All what I need is to drag an image to IE web page and the path of this file will be uploaded.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `drag-n-drop upload activex internet explorer`?

Comment: This is, as far as I know, supported by the HTML5 File API, which IE9 only supports partially (IE 10 will support fully). [Please see this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)#Related_specifications).

Comment: @yoda : yes I tried, but in vain :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know so much about this but as an idea you could use an Java applet, or as somebody else suggested an Adobe Flash script.
Or you might check if IE supports HTML5 File Api (http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) ... less likely

Comment: No IE doesn't support Html5 File API, I am working now on IE8, but will upgrade to IE9 according tp UWe Keim's post

Comment: I found a great solution, check this
[link](http://browserplus.org/docs/web_dev/example_code/drag_and_drop_v1.html)